# String search logic - not language specific

Tags: string, logic

I'm having to check data entry on an address field. The client does not want users to use terms like Rd. or Rd for road, ave or ave. for avenue etc. I have no problem with most of the terms. Where I have issues is with 'Ave' lets say. If I look for ' AVE ', that's fine but it will not pick up on ' AVE' at the end of the string and if I look for ' AVE' it will get a false positive on ' Avenue' since it will find ' Ave' within that string. Anyone have an idea of how I can go about this?

Thank you for any help.
Norst

Although the Q: is not language specific, here is how I'm going about this in JS:

```
    //function to check address for rd rd. ave ave. st st. etc
function checkaddy() {
    //array of items to look for
    var watchfor = Array();
    watchfor[0] = " RD";
    watchfor[1] = " RD.";
    watchfor[2] = " AVE ";
    watchfor[3] = " AVE.";
    watchfor[4] = " ST ";
    watchfor[5] = " ST.";
    watchfor[6] = " BLVD.";
    watchfor[7] = " CRT ";
    watchfor[8] = " CRT.";
    watchfor[9] = " CRES ";
    watchfor[10] = " CRES.";
    watchfor[11] = " E ";
    watchfor[12] = " E.";
    watchfor[13] = " W ";
    watchfor[14] = " W.";
    watchfor[15] = " N ";
    watchfor[16] = " N.";
    watchfor[17] = " S ";
    watchfor[18] = " S.";
    watchfor[19] = " PKWY ";
    watchfor[20] = " PKWY.";
    watchfor[21] = " DR ";
    watchfor[22] = " DR.";

    //get what the user has in the address box
    var addcheck = $("#address").val();

    //upper case the address to check
    addcheck = addcheck.toUpperCase();

    //check to see if any of these terms are in our address
    watchfor.forEach(function(i) {
        if (addcheck.search(watchfor[i]) > 0 ) {
            alert("Found One!");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try and give a better visual representation of what you mean. I'm not really following

Comment: Sounds like you need regular expressions. Javascript I presume? ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to look for word boundary character `\b`. Here are some Ruby examples:

```
irb(main):002:0> " Avenue" =~ / AVE\b/i
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> " Ave" =~ / AVE\b/i
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> " Ave" =~ /\bAVE\b/i
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> " Ave" =~ /\bAVE\b/i
```

Notice how `" Avenue"` doesn't match while `" AVE"` does match. Also notice how the `'\b'` behaves and we get `0` and `1` respectively.

There are other characters classes as well in regular expressions. So all you need to do is formulate correct REs for your problem set.

I hope that helps.

Comment: tuxdna, yes it looks like I do need to use RE's, I have not used them much as I'm still learning. These seem to be able to do what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I checked it but I can't up yet as I do not have the rep required :o( and yes it was very helpful. Just need to figure out how to put RegExp's in my array :o)

Answer (score 0):

Why would your client insist on spelling out names?  The United States Postal Service actually encourages abbreviations.  Not only that, they prefer addresses to be in all uppercase letters and no more than 5 lines.  Such specifications are what their automated sorters were built for.  But I digress.

To actually answer your question, you may consider the following code.  There was a mistake in your `forEach` declaration.  You were using `i` as an index, but, in fact, the `forEach` function uses the whole entry of the array.  I modified it below.  Also, because we're using a string expression in the constructor for the RegExp, the `\` in the `\b` has to be escaped, so we add two `\`'s inside the string.  Because we using the `\b` construct for word boundaries, we don't need to add extra periods into the test array.  I hope you find this helpful.

```
//array of items to look for
var watchfor = ['RD','AVE','ST','BLVD','CRT','CRES','E','W','N','S','PKWY','DR'];

//function to check address for rd rd. ave ave. st st. etc
function checkaddy(address) {

    //check to see if any of these terms are in our address
    watchfor.forEach(function(entry) {
        var patt1 = RegExp('.*\\b' + entry + '\\b.*','gim');
        if (patt1.test(address)) {
            document.write("Found " + entry);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the trimmed down version of my function, I was in the middle of rewriting it when I saw this. Yes I do have an error in my loop. I ended up using $.each(watchfor, function(i) {...}) As for the client, I totally agree but they have internal comments that are looked up by address so they need to make sure they are entered consistently. I think it's silly but I can only argue my point so much.